# Pick video from gallery with size limit in android

Tags: gallery, android-videoview

My requirement is pick video from gallery less than 25MB and show in my layout in android App.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below line of code to get the every video limit

```
 String[] projection = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
};


 Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    collection,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    sortOrder
            )
            int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {               
                int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);              
                videoList.add(new Video(contentUri, name, duration, size));
            }
```

Another way of get this using when in case of intent or ur need

```
 File file = new File(parent,"test.mp4" );
        Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
        long lengthSize = file.length();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        lengthSize = file.length();
```